# Quickest way to find the largest file in a directory and subdirectories

Tags: shell-script, files, sort, size

I need to find the largest file in the current and subsequent directory. I tried

```
ls -Rlh | awk '{print $3 " " $5 " " $9}'
```

but do not know if it is ok, how to sort and select the largest file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GNU **`find`** + **`sort`** + **`head`** solution (for any directory depth level), assuming file paths don't contain newline characters:

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -1
```

- `%s` - format specificator pointing to file size (in bytes)
- `%p` - format specificator pointing to file name
- `sort -nr` - sort records numerically in reversed order
- `head -1` - print the TOP first line/record

---

To get a *human-readable* file size value - extend the pipeline with GNU `numfmt` command (if supported):

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -1 | numfmt --to=si
```

Comment: I would need human readable disk usage. Do you have any recommendations? It works perfect so far.

Comment: @JamesW, se my update

Comment: Worked perfect! I didn't know there is an actual function for converting to human readable

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, for the biggest regular file:

```
ls -ld -- **/*(.DOL[1])
```

(of course you can replace `ls -ld --` with any command. If using GNU `ls` or compatible see also the `-h` option for *human readable sizes*)

- `.`: only *regular* files (not directories, symlinks, devices, fifos...)
- `D`: include hidden ones and descend into hidden dirs
- `OL`: reverse-ordered by size (`L`ength).
- `[1]`: only the first match.

If there are ties, you'll get any one of them at random. If you want the first in alphabetical order, add an extra `on` (`o`rder by `n`ame) to sort ties alphabetically.

Comment: I might do something wrong but it does not work

Comment: @JamesW, I suspect you missed the _"With `zsh`"_ part. What shell are you trying it in? In which way does it not work?

Comment: I am running bash. So I have to put that in a script, right and execute with zsh. Can I do it straight from the command line?

Comment: From `bash`, you can always do `zsh -c 'ls -ld -- **/*(.DOL[1])'` but if you're often finding yourself looking for the _quickest way_, you may want to consider switching your shell to `zsh` (also for _safest way_ , _best way_ and _more efficient way_).